# Box Java SDK setting tag to a folder

Tags: java, box, boxsdk

I want to add tag to a folder which shall be uploaded into box.
Below one does not seem to work. 
I have enabled tags for my account in box from web UI

> final BoxFolder uploadFolder = new BoxFolder(this.boxAPIConnection,
>   parentFolderId);
>   uploadFolder.getInfo().setTags(Arrays.asList("myTag"));

Looking at the code in com.box.sdk.BoxFolder#uploadFile(com.box.sdk.FileUploadParams) does not seem to consider the tag at all. Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>         final BoxFolder folder = new BoxFolder(this.boxAPIConnection, folderId);
>         final BoxFolder.Info folderInfo = folder.getInfo();
>         folderInfo.setTags(Arrays.asList(tag));
>         folder.updateInfo(folderInfo);
> ```

Apparently another. API call. If someone has better solution, please do suggest

Comment: This is the best way and is exactly as documented here: https://developer.box.com/guides/folders/single/update/

Comment: Shouldn't we have an option to set the tags during folder creation.Why do you say this is the best way

Comment: Unfortunately, the folder has to be created before tags can be added to it; the two steps can't be combined into one operation.